# Downloading nltk in AWS EMR gives '[Errno 28] No space left on device'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, emr, amazon-emr

I'm Getting 'No Space' error while running the below code in Amazon AWS EMR cluster.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('all')
```

I checked the memory in commandline, Below is the screenshot of the available memory [available memory in the cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bstcT.png). Please usher me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There NLTK downloader downloads the data to the directory `/usr/share/nltk_data/` on Unix/Linux based Operating Systems.

Download this data on a different location where there is sufficient diskspace and write access.

```
python -m nltk.downloader -d /mnt/nltk_data all
```

Since the default data location is changed now, set the `NLTK_DATA` environment variable accordingly.

```
export NLTK_DATA=/mnt/nltk_data
```

Your instance seems to have ran out of diskspace under root.
The `/` directory is filled to 100%, Free some diskspace before proceeding.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have one more query: is it okay to download nltk data in s3fs and set the environment variable pointing to that path? I am trying to download in s3fs but it is taking quite amount of time to download the data.

Comment: Mount your S3 bucket to a mount point and set the path to `NLTK_DATA`. I have not tried this myself, but ideally it should work.

Comment: @coder007, did you store the files in S3 and use the NLTK_DATA path to reference the files? did it work?

Comment: @user422930 Yes it worked. I mounted a s3 bucket and downloaded the data into it. In the end, make sure to set the NLTK_DATA path to this mount directory.